# More than 5 time my Website show this issue

Tags: installation

Hy, I am beginner of wordpress,
Why my webiste Show this issue again and again
Problem ScreenShot given below
please help to resolve my issue

[image: Wordpress error]

Comment: I don't remember precisely what triggers that, but I'd guess you're losing your wp-config settings or your database or both. Can you work out which, and what's dropping them / rebuilding your environment without them?

Comment: This is an issue you should take up with your hosting provider.